# Simplify a do-while loop

Tags: java

Is it ok to do this to simplify a `do-while` loop? or should `for` only be used for incrementing/decrementing?

```
    String res;
    for(res=null;res==null;res=op.getOrderID());
```

**instead of:**

```
    String res = null;
    do {
        res = op.getRetOrderID()
    } while (res == null);
```

Comment: Why the downvotes without comments? (Or close votes? Or dupes?) This is an interesting question.

Comment: _only be used for incrementing/decrementing_ Why would you think so?

Comment: Define _ok_. What do you think can go wrong?

Comment: perhaps because I could have written the do while on 2 lines also )

Comment: Does it simplify the code in your opinion? Does it simplify the code in my opinion? Not really.

Comment: well, at first I wasn't thinking I could write do-while more concisely - and in my code I need multiple loops so, I was thinking it would give some space savings. now I realize that do while on 2 lines is definitely clearer code than using a for loop

Comment: It's a dangerous play... It may eat all your CPU and hang.. You probably would like to define an exit condition / timeout. So It will not be a one line operation anyway. So why to bother about loop type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to stick with the `do-while` loop. This is the standard idiom for the situation when you want the body of the loop to be executed at least once.

One good reason for sometimes using a `for` loop in preference to a `while` or `do-while` loop is that you can make the variable checked in the termination condition local to the loop. You definitely don't want that here as you need it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Advice :

1. use for loop when you know the number of repetitions .
2. use while loop when you do not know the number of repetitions .
3. use do-while loop when you want to run your code one time at least and do          not know the number of repetitions .

Good Luck .